# Conflict in software update policies when installing desktop on top of server?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt

For convenience during development (not sure yet if I will do this in production), I decided to install desktop (via tasksel) on 14.04 server, to allow interaction with this machine via both desktop and cmd-line, including in the latter case using gnu screen. (using alt-fn keys to get to terminals). This is to learn to interact without presence of the desktop, yet in this case for max. convenience also have the desktop available. But it's fully intended that this setup is for a server that will eventually go into production and therefore security matters a lot.

What I understand: apt-get in 14.04 server will not automatically upgrade to 14.10, this being LTS release policy (it says updates 'held back').

Yet when I am in the desktop, software update is telling me I have a security update. If I understand correctly this is really the kernel updates which make up 14.10 upgrade.

Which messages should I rely on?  Should I just ignore what desktop software update says?  A bit uncomfortable doing that.

Comment: use a web interface on servers such as cockpit webmin or similar. There are several available http://cockpit-project.org/ and https://launchpad.net/~jpsutton/+archive/ubuntu/cockpit and http://www.ubuntugeek.com/cockpit-a-remote-manager-for-gnulinux-servers.html

Answer (score 1):

Desktop software updater asks explicitly about updating to the next version. So, if it's about 14.10 then it'll be stated as such.

Kernel updates can come any time. And they don't mean that the distribution version will change.

Comment: Thanks.  I've realised now that if I want both the convenience of a desktop system for web browsing, apps and the like, and in addition to be running a solid server, a more sensible setup may be to use a separate desktop machine to access a separate server machine via a terminal and to run gnu screen on the server, inside that terminal on the desktop. This gives me all that I was wanting above, but was trying to achieve on one machine.  With two machines, it feels a lot better engineering-wise and safer (rather obvious really...).  :)  fun to try things out though.. ta

Comment: @mwal: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**